# in mongodb documnets date fields chagefrom month to date

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a 6000 records with a problem: test_date is saved wrongly; for example for a date in the 2nd month the data is mistakenly saved as the 4th month:

```
"test_date" : ISODate("2017-04-02T00:00:00.000+0000"),
```

I need to change month to 02 and date to 04; I need a query to run on mongochef to change these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use $set to update fields in mongodb,

```
         db.collection.update({
            "test_date": ISODate("2017-04-02T00:00:00.000+0000")
         }, {
            $set: {
                "test_date": ISODate("2017-02-04T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }
         }, {
            multi: true
         });
```

Note: this command will set same date "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD" for  all matches